How do I retrieve the Execution Id for a job in Spring Cloud Data Flow?
In my Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) dashboard under "Tasks/Jobs" -> "Job Executions" there is an overview of all the jobs that have run so far with their status. The first column of that overview is the Execution Id. That's also the id in the url when you click on a specific job execution eg: https://yourserver/dashboard/index.html#/tasks-jobs/job-executions/2902/schemaTarget/boot2. The 2902 there is the execution id.
I have a spring boot application where I have a org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowOperations instance I use to retrieve jobs. I can find the Job status etc but I cannot find the execution id and that's what I want.
I have tried:
dataFlowOperations.jobOperations().jobExecution(jobId, null).getExecutionId() --> gives back instance id
dataFlowOperations.jobOperations().jobExecution(jobId, null).getJobExecution().getId() --> also gives back instance id
Those are the only attributes I can find that (going by naming) could be the execution id but they are not.  I checked the documentation but it wasn't very helpful either.
Does anyone know how to retrieve the execution id ?

dataFlowOperations.jobOperations().jobExecution(jobId, null).getJobExecution().getId() should give you the Execution Id.   Maybe the two ids can be the same if only executed once.

I checked locally while connecting to the QA environment of SCDF and now I see the jobId parameter you pass with .jobExecution(jobid, null) IS in fact the execution id. And now I see dataFlowOperations.jobOperations().jobExecution(jobId, null).getJobExecution().getId() is also indeed the Execution Id. I could have sworn I saw different things yesterday, maybe I was just tired.

I know what probably happened: We're using kubernetes so the pod with the old code was probably not evicted yet.
